# How to write formly template to set ng-tags-input's auto-complete source?

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input, angular-formly

I'm trying to write a custom formly template to use ng-tags-input:

```
angular.module('myMod').run(function(formlyConfig) {
    formlyConfig.setType({
        name:'tag',
        template:"<label class='control-label' ng-if='to.label'>{{to.label}}</label>" +
        "<tags-input ng-model='model[options.key]' ng-attr-placeholder='{{to.placeholder}}'>" +
        "<auto-complete source='{{to.tags}}'></auto-complete></tags-input>"
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    });
})
```

where `to.tags` refers to the formly template's templateOptions:

```
            templateOptions: {
                tags: 'dataModel.getProductTags()'
```

Using double-braces in this context causes a $parse error.  How can I fill that *`source`* attribute indirectly from the content of `to.tags`?

I've also tried `ng-attr-source='to.tags'`, with no luck.

I suspect I'm just not thinking of something obvious.  If easy and sensible, please include relevant references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to put the function, not the name of the function, in templateOptions, like so:

```
            templateOptions: {
                tags: dataModel.getProductTags
```

and in the template, just invoke it:

```
<auto-complete source='to.tags()'>
```

This requires that the function itself must be accessible from the formly template, but in my case that's not a problem.